# Issue when storing NSDictionary into the PAPreferences

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdictionary

```
@interface ConfGlobal : PAPreferences

@property (nonatomic, assign) NSDictionary *dtUsersDetails;
```

Get NSDictionary from REST response

NSDictionary *dtResult =[rest getResult];

```
        [ConfGlobal sharedInstance].dtUsersDetails =  dtResult;
```

And catch the following error:

2015-05-03 14:33:48.018 Autoban Service[9940:2644989] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'This object is not a valid plist

Please, give me the idea, there is the issue? 
Thanks in advance

Comment: This error means you should check the structure of the file you are trying to load. Something's wrong there. And also you should be using `strong` for types like `NSDictionary`.

Comment: It should be assign for all properties.

Requirements for library (note that all properties should have an assign storage specifier)